# Problem on numbered books order in a shelf

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Problem: We have 40 books on a shelf randomly arranged. Three books are a series and have numbers - 1,2,3. Need to find the probability that they'll be arranged at ascending order, like 1 comes earlier than 2, and 2 earlier than 3, but they need not to be right after each other. Like this case is possible (1.....2......3)

Now I managed to find the probability when 123 come right after each other. It is about $0.00064$. But I can't find a strategy to solve the above mentioned one. Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please note that --ignoring the spaces in between them-- there are only six ways to order these three books: (123), (132), (213), (231), (312) and (321). Since the books are randomly arranged, each of this six orderings must have the same probability. Which is therefore $1/6$. So that is your answer.

Comment: @M.Wind You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the symmetry argument of M. Wind produces an elegant solution.

Here, I present a solution "on combinatorical foot":

- First, arrange the $37$ other books: $\color{blue}{37!}$
- These $37$ books offer $38$ "slots" where to put the $3$ books in the given specific order: $\color{green}{38}$
- In each "slot" $s_i$ $(i=1,\ldots, \color{green}{38})$ you can put $s_i =0,1,2,3$ books, such that $s_1 + \cdots +s_{\color{green}{38}} = \color{orange}{3}$. As the order of the books is fixed, you get as the number of ways (using the formula for combinations with repetitions): $\binom{\color{green}{n}+\color{orange}{k}-1}{\color{orange}{k}}=\color{blue}{\binom{40}{3}}$

It follows:
$$P(\text{books of series appear in ascending order}) = \frac{\color{blue}{37!\cdot \binom{40}{3}}}{40!} = \frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: You made a computational mistake.  Note that your $n = 38$ and your $k = 3$, so $\binom{n + k - 1}{k} = \binom{38 + 3 - 1}{3} = \binom{40}{3}$.  The answer reduces to $1/6$, which can be more easily obtained by using a symmetry argument.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: OOOps. Thanks. Sometimes adding and subtracting isn't that easy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that --ignoring the spaces in between them-- there are only six ways to order these three books: (123), (132), (213), (231), (312) and (321). Since the books are randomly arranged, each of this six orderings must have the same probability. Which is therefore 1/6. So that is your answer.